# Extracting audio from vlc in lua

Tags: lua, vlc, libvlc

I am writing an vlc addon in lua. The addon is about recognizing speech from currently playing video. So i need to extract portions of audio from  currently playing file. But i am unable to figure out how to do this. I can get the audio object as `object.aout()` but i have no idea what i can do with it, the docs says nothing.

The only lua addon documentation i could find was [this](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt) and its horrible for a beginner. Also is there any interactive console for lua like ipython where i can just see all available properties and functions? I tried debugger its just basic interpreter.

Comment: google vlc audio output object, get: https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__audio__output.html#gad643b1ec4fe5c68784eb660c08e725c3
I guess that's the same audio output object wrapped in the lua interface.

Comment: Thanks @Piglet, apparently i cant cut an audio from the audio object, i can only control the playback params

Comment: just contact the guys at videolan...
you could just process your systems audio output if you cannot access it through the VLC API if VLC allows you to load external modules.